# ¿Como mostrar el texto en diagonal en el extremo superior de una imagen con CSS?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, style

Actualmente muestro un texto en el extremo superior de una imagen:

```css
 .container {
  position: relative;
}

.text-block {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color:#17d90d;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding:5px;
  

}
```

```html
<h2>Image Text Blocks</h2>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/360" alt="Nature" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="text-block">
    Oferta
  </div>
</div>
```

Pero que deseo es que la palabra oferta se muestre en diagonal, e intentado con rotate, pero me sale mal.
Lo que deseo es que se vea así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que el texto de la palabra oferta se muestre igual al de la foto.
¿Como se podría hacer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esta es una forma de hacerlo, agregando un contenedor para darle la forma triangular, y rotando el texto:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

#triangle-topleft {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 100px solid #17d90d;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  }

.text-block {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  left: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding:5px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<h2>Image Text Blocks</h2>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/360" alt="Nature" style="width:100%;">
  <div id="triangle-topleft">
    <div class="text-block">
      Oferta
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @BetaM gracias por el voto y por el comentario, edité la respuesta con una pequeña explicación

Answer (score 0):

principalmente deberías agregar una etiqueta a tu texto para que puedas manipular solo esa sección algo asi:

```html
<h2>Image Text Blocks</h2>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/360" alt="Nature" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="text-block">
    <span>Oferta</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

ahora dentro de tu css agregas la siguiente linea:

```css
.text-block span {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
 }
```

Espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero no cambia